# How can I zoom an element by scrolling?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am currently learning javascript and have encountered a problem that got me stuck:
I have a `div` with a `90% height` and a `80% width`.
I'm trying to make this `div` grow when scrolling to reach a full screen size (needs to occupy the whole display)(`100% width`, `100% height`).

I've tried for and do-while loops, but it doesn't seem to be working.
It seems as if the `height` and `width` of the `div` do not change the element's style.

Does anyone know how to fix this ?
I am really looking forwards to any tips you can give me in order to achieve my project and learn from my mistakes.

Below is my current code :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

   $(window).scroll(function(e){

      var pos = $(window).scrollTop();
      
      console.log("Scroll:" +pos);
      
      var div = document.getElementsByClassName('home');
      
      if(pos>300){
         let h = 90 + (pos/150);
         let w = 80 + 1 +(pos/50);

         if(h>100){
            h = 100;
         }

         if(w>100){
            w = 100;
         }

         h = " \" " + h + " %\"";
         w = " \" " + w + " %\"";

         console.log(h);

         document.getElementsByClassName('home').height = Math.round(h);
         document.getElementsByClassName('home').width = Math.round(w);
      }
   });
});
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    font-family:-apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
    background-color: #CBCACA;
}

.wrapper{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

.home{
    height: 90%;
    width: 80%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 5%;
    left: 10%;
    border-radius: 50px;
    background-color: #302D2D;
}

.supply{
    height: 100vh;
    width: 70%;
    position: relative;
    left: 15%;
    margin-top: 100%;
    background-color: crimson;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>Timo Roedler</title>
        <meta name="description" content="small test with Scrolling">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="headline">

            </div>
            <div class="main">
                <div class="home">
                    
                </div>
                <div class="supply">
                    <div class="supply1">
                        
                    </div>
                    <div class="supply2">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="app.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You might want to consider using `transform: scale(x)` instead of width / height to zoom on objects. They will expand from the center.

Answer (score 3):

Very good effort.  You just have a few things that are incorrect.

#### Targeting the element

Right now, you have the following code.

```
var div = document.getElementsByClassName('home');
```

In this you are trying to target your "home" element and the syntax is correct, but it will not return the node.  [`.getElementsByClassName()` returns an array-like object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName), which means that you would need to access it using `document.getElementsByClassName('home')[0]` or `div[0]`.  Personally, I prefer using [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector), but you could also use jQuery to get the element you're after.

#### Applying the style

Here's your code:

```
h = " \" " + h + " %\"";

document.getElementsByClassName('home').height = Math.round(h)
```

First, the nature of strings in JavaScript allow you to simply use `h = h + '%'`.  Also, if you need to include quotes in a string (you don't here, but it may be useful to know), you can wrap them in single quotes instead: `var message = 'the "name" field is required.'`  Once you have a string, you can't use `Math.round()` on it anymore.  `Math.round()` only accepts a number.  In this case, however, there's no need to round.  You can use the unrounded value, but you shouldn't apply it to `.height`.  That property is outdated and it's preferable to assign to the CSS style property, which is `.style.height`.

#### Centering your element

In your code, you attempt to offset the element using 5% and 10% top and left respectively.  You'll have to change those too as you change the height, or you can use transforms to center your element like so:

```
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

Overall, good effort and good luck on your efforts to learn JavaScript.  It's a very fun language to learn.  Below I've included a code snippet with those changes.  Hopefully it'll help demonstrate the information above.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

   $(window).scroll(function(e){

      var pos = $(window).scrollTop();
      
      //console.log("Scroll:" +pos);
      
      var div = document.querySelector('.home');
      
      if(pos>300){
         let h = 90 + (pos/150);
         let w = 80 + 1 +(pos/50);

         if(h>100){
            h = 100;
         }

         if(w>100){
            w = 100;
         }

         h = h + "%";
         w = w + "%";

         //console.log(h);

         document.querySelector('.home').style.height = h;
         document.querySelector('.home').style.width = w;
      }
   });
});
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    font-family:-apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
    background-color: #CBCACA;
}

.wrapper{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

.home{
    height: 90%;
    width: 80%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    border-radius: 50px;
    background-color: #302D2D;
}

.supply{
    height: 100vh;
    width: 70%;
    position: relative;
    left: 15%;
    margin-top: 100%;
    background-color: crimson;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>Timo Roedler</title>
        <meta name="description" content="small test with Scrolling">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="headline">

            </div>
            <div class="main">
                <div class="home">
                    
                </div>
                <div class="supply">
                    <div class="supply1">
                        
                    </div>
                    <div class="supply2">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="app.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ohh wow, thank you so much. The explanation is better and more detailed than I expected. Can't thank you enoug!
I am really desperate the last two days, and without your halp probably the next days too.

Answer (score 0):

At a cursory look it might have something to do with these lines

```
     // You were trying to use Math.round on a string.
     h = Math.round(h) + "%";
     w = Math.round(w) + "%";
     console.log(h);
     // assign the percentage directly to the style
     document.getElementsByClassName('home').style.height = h;
     document.getElementsByClassName('home').style.width = w;
```